# CRecord DoFieldExchange Warning: float converted from sql type 8

Tags: mfc

I have an MFC application that has a DoFieldExchange extracting data from a MS Access 2010 database.

It works, the problem is that on the DebugOutput I have a 
Warning: float converted from SQL to type 8.

Does anyone know why this is ?

The database has 12 columns, which in the Access DB it's just number and text data types. On MFC it's using RFX_Long, RFX_Int, RFX_Text.

EDIT:

I narrowed it down to 
where m_FloatValue is a float.
RFX_Single(pFX, _T("[FloatValue]"), m_FloatValue);
This warning happens when FloatValue is 1.25 or 1.0 for example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Rules are simple around here: No code, no help.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem was that the guy who did the database had that field as a Double in the database, not as a Single(float).

Therefore, it had to do a typecast to convert from Double to Float in MFC.